# Adding odata version 4 controller scaffolding in visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, controller, odata, odata-v4

How do i add an odata v4 controller scaffold in visual studio 2013? i have installed the odatalib(5.6) and alaong with all the dependencies and using entity framework. i am able to see an option for odata 3 but cannot find any option for odata version 4. I am a novice in this technology. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the VSIX from: [OData v4 Web API Scaffolding](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LiangWangMSFT.ODatav4WebAPIScaffolding) and try again

Comment: I am new to .net and visual studio. How do i add this scaffolding to my Visual studio?